# Generation of designer file failed: The directive is missing a 'tagprefix' attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, ide

When adding a reference to a user control in my web project, I type

```
<%@ Register
```

Then the IDE steals my focus and puts it in the Error List pane, on the error

> "Generation of designer file failed:
>   The directive is missing a 'tagprefix'
>   attribute."

Obviously there isn't a tagprefix attribute yet, I'm still typing the tag!

How can I stop Visual Studio from moving focus to the Error List pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any that I know of. You might want to log it as a bug using [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Fingers crossed for a fix in the next service pack.